# Bootstrap modal not rendered correctly

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, reactjs

I have copied the sample code of a modal from the Bootstrap website:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo

I am displaying it from a react component when a button is clicked:

```
Modal = React.createClass({
    render: function(){

        return(
        //MODAL CODE
        )
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, when I click the button which should trigger the rendering of the modal, the modal is displayed within the page, like a form rather than being displayed above all other content.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show much. Can you post all the code inside the `createClass` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you replaced "class" with "className" in the code which you copied from bootstrap website?

Comment: That's exactly what I had forgotten. Thank you!